# ¿Cómo mostrar el nombre del empleado, cuantos tickets tiene pendientes y cuantos tickets tiene resueltos en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Muy buen día, tengo estas 3 tablas en MySQL:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde el campo `asignar` en la tabla `ticket` va el id de la tabla `employee` y el campo `estatus` va el id de la tabla `status`. He intentado hacer una consulta que me muestre el nombre y apellido (concatenados en la misma columna), el número de tickets que tiene pendientes y el número de tickets que tiene resueltos.

Al ejecutar el siguiente Query:

```
SELECT * FROM ticket
```

Los id del estatus del 1 al 3 hacen referencia a un estatus `abierto` y los ID del estatus del 4 al 6 hacen referencia a un estatus `resuelto`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT (employee.id AS agente_id, 
CONCAT(employee.nom, ' ', employee.ape) AS agente, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ticket WHERE (ticket.estatus = 1 || ticket.estatus = 2 || ticket.estatus = 3)GROUP BY agente_id) AS asignados, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ticket WHERE (ticket.estatus = 4 || ticket.estatus = 5 || ticket.estatus = 6)GROUP BY agente_id) AS resueltos )
FROM ticket 
INNER JOIN employee ON ticket.asignar = employee.id 
GROUP BY agente_id;
```

El código anterior me muestra el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando el resultado esperado es parecido al siguiente (IMAGEN DE EXCEL):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El siguiente es otro intento:

```
SELECT employee.id AS agente_id, 
CONCAT(employee.nom, ' ', employee.ape) AS agente, 
COUNT(DISTINCT(ticket.estatus)) 
FROM ticket INNER JOIN employee ON ticket.asignar = employee.id 
GROUP BY ticket.asignar;
```

Y tengo este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu consulta:

```
SELECT (employee.id AS agente_id, 
CONCAT(employee.nom, ' ', employee.ape) AS agente, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ticket WHERE (ticket.estatus = 1 || ticket.estatus = 2 || ticket.estatus = 3)GROUP BY agente_id) AS asignados, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ticket WHERE (ticket.estatus = 4 || ticket.estatus = 5 || ticket.estatus = 6)GROUP BY agente_id) AS resueltos )
FROM ticket 
INNER JOIN employee ON ticket.asignar = employee.id 
GROUP BY agente_id;
```

te hace falta incluir el `WHERE` para identificar el empleado; de la forma que lo tienes básicamente hace el conteo de todo en la tabla; solo estás filtrando por el `status`. Prueba lo siguiente

```
SELECT (employee.id AS agente_id, 
CONCAT(employee.nom, ' ', employee.ape) AS agente, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ticket AS tk WHERE (tk.estatus = 1 || tk.estatus = 2 || tk.estatus = 3) AND tk.asignar = employee.id GROUP BY agente_id) AS asignados, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ticket AS tk WHERE (tk.estatus = 4 || tk.estatus = 5 || tk.estatus = 6) AND tk.asignar = employee.id GROUP BY agente_id) AS resueltos )
FROM ticket 
INNER JOIN employee ON ticket.asignar = employee.id 
GROUP BY agente_id;
```

Usé alias para que se vea que ticket no corresponde a referencia en la consulta principal sino del subquery. Espero te sea de utilidad.